# Paging in Listview with a dynamic number of rows group

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listview, custompaging, custom-paging

I'm working on an exam system .
 I created a List view to display all the Multiple choice or True false Questions then I need to set the paging to 5 Questions per page.

The issue here is the total of the multiple choices Answers for each question changing {1choice,2choices,3choices,4choices or 5choices} the paging interact with each answer as it's a row while I need to deal with it as a group(Question with the Answers) in order to show only 5 questions on each page.

please Advice,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem in easiest way by using

```
NTILE(10) OVER(ORDER BY QuestionID ASC) AS Pagenumber
```

in my SQL this will divide all the rows in 10 groups depending on `QuestionID`

For example :

```
QUestionID    Pagenumber
QUestionID 11              Pagenumber   1
QUestionID 11                Pagenumber 1
QUestionID 11                Pagenumber 1
QUestionID 11                Pagenumber 1
QUestionID 12                Pagenumber 2
QUestionID 12               Pagenumber  2
QUestionID 30                Pagenumber 3
QUestionID 30                Pagenumber 3
QUestionID 30               Pagenumber  3
QUestionID 44               Pagenumber  4
QUestionID 67               Pagenumber  5
QUestionID 67               Pagenumber  5
QUestionID 67               Pagenumber  5
```

and so in till I get 10 groups in my page number column

Then on the first call my list view will `select * where pagenumber = 1`, on second call it will send the page number as query string incremented by 1 so, on second call `select * where pagenumber = 2` .. until I reached page 10

I hope that can help someone :)